# AngualrJS $watchCollection triggers even when arrays are equal

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement an auto sync between my angularJS model and my database.

I am running the following function every ten seconds to get data from from database in which I update my variable **products_copy**:

```
$interval(function(){$scope.getProductsSync();},10000);

$scope.getProductsSync = function() {
    var q = $q.defer(); 
    $http({
        url: '/getData/getProducts.php',
        method: "POST",
        data: {"user_id":$scope.user_id}
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        if(response.data.valid)
        {
            console.log('Products sync complete: '+new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
            console.log(response.data.products);
            $scope.products_copy = response.data.products;
            q.resolve('Products sync complete');
        }
        else if(response.data.msg=="offline")
        {
            console.log('Products sync offline');
            q.resolve('Products sync offline');
        }       
        else
        {
            console.log('Products sync error');
            console.log(response);
            q.reject('Products sync error');
        }
    }, 
    function(response) {
        console.log('Products sync error'); 
        console.log(response);      
        q.reject('Products sync error');
    });
    return q.promise;               
    }
```

Whenever there is a change in this data I want to update my actual product list in my model which is defined by the array **products**. Hence, I am using the service $watchCollection to detect a change in the data and update my model when there is a change. However this change is triggered in each call even though the data from the database is unchanged.

```
$scope.$watchCollection('products_copy', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
    if(newValue!==oldValue)
    {
    console.log('Watch on products was called');
    console.log('Old value: '+oldValue);
    console.log('New value: '+newValue);
    $scope.products = newValue;
    }
});
```

I want the event to be triggered only when there is change in the array such as:

1. add item
2. remove item
3. edit any property of any item

EDIT 1:

I changed it to angular.equals but even that resulted in trigger in every call. However, when I examined each item in the console I realised angular was adding a property $$hashkey which was varying between the items. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try for angular.equal(object1, object2)

```
$scope.$watchCollection('products_copy', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
    if(!angular.equals(newValue, oldValue))
    {
    console.log('Watch on products was called');
    console.log('Old value: '+oldValue);
    console.log('New value: '+newValue);
    $scope.products = newValue;
    }
});
```

Comment: It's `angular.equals` with a **s**

Comment: I tried using angular.equals but still it triggers everytime. However i checked each item in the console and realised there is something called $$hashkey which is being inserted in each item which is different in each new fetch. This is resulting in them being unequal. Any idea how i solve this?

Comment: so one thing that may help you is to use "track by" in ng-repeat where you generating the list/table. Angular says: "when we use ‘track by’, angular no longer adds $$hashkey to the array."

Comment: I am using this array only in my script. It has not been used anywhere in the view and certainly not in any ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

It is how it should be, because on each response you assign a new reference to $scope.products_copy and no matter that there're no changes of the data inside it, when you do newValue!==oldValue you compare the refereces, they are always different

if you try

```
var a = [];
var b = [];
console.log(a===b); // false

// the both are empty and seems to be equal
```

you have to check the data inside old and new data. Try with `angular.equals`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that angular was inserting a $$hashKey attribute which resulted in a difference even in same objects. Removing this field did the trick for me.